# Missing Class after Maven Install

Tags: java, maven

So I've pretty much been banging my head against the wall trying to solve this one...

This is my first time using Maven, and am using it on OSX to install the ews-java-api.

After clean, or instal, and everything builds successfully, but I am still unable to access the classes through a java file.

I'm getting the following errors,

```
    Connect.java:3: error: package microsoft.exchange.webservices.data does not exist
    import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.*;
    Connect.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
    ^
    symbol:   class ExchangeService
    location: class Connect
```

I'm curious if I've overall made a mistake with the install path, when installing Maven... or if theres another issue regarding where I'm downloading the A.P.I package?

Any help is much appreciated!!

[EDIT]
This is my bash.profile output...

```
    $ cat ~/.bash_profile 
    export M2_HOME=/Users/joliv64/mailtests/apache-maven-3.3.3/
    export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

Also this is my pom.xml file.

```
       <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.microsoft.ews-java-api</groupId>
<artifactId>ews-java-api</artifactId>

<version>3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>Exchange Web Services Java API</name>
<description>Exchange Web Services (EWS) Java API</description>

<!-- Required by the site command for certain relative URL configuration. -->
<url>http://www.microsoft.com/</url>

<!-- Used by the javadoc plugin to generate the comments at the bottom. -->
<inceptionYear>2012</inceptionYear>

<!-- Used to define a minimum Maven version. Used in conjunction with plugin
    management to lock in a more current version of the various plugins. -->
<prerequisites>
    <maven>3.1.0</maven>
</prerequisites>

<organization>
    <name>Microsoft</name>
    <url>http://www.microsoft.com/</url>
</organization>

<properties>
    <!-- Eliminates the file encoding warning. Of course, all of your files
        should probably be UTF-8 nowadays. -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <javaLanguage.version>1.6</javaLanguage.version>
    <javadoc.doclint.param/>

    <!--  Dependencies [BUILD]:  -->
    <maven-gpg-plugin.version>1.6</maven-gpg-plugin.version>
    <maven-javadoc-plugin.version>2.10.3</maven-javadoc-plugin.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.3</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <nexus-staging-maven-plugin.version>1.6.5</nexus-staging-maven-plugin.version>
    <maven-source-plugin.version>2.4</maven-source-plugin.version>
    <animal-sniffer-maven-plugin.version>1.14</animal-sniffer-maven-plugin.version>
    <animal-sniffer-maven-plugin.signature.version>1.1</animal-sniffer-maven-plugin.signature.version>
    <!--  Dependencies [REPORT]:  -->
    <maven-site-plugin.version>3.4</maven-site-plugin.version>
    <maven-project-info-reports-plugin.version>2.8</maven-project-info-reports-plugin.version>
    <versions-maven-plugin.version>2.2</versions-maven-plugin.version>
    <maven-jxr-plugin.version>2.5</maven-jxr-plugin.version>
    <maven-surefire-report-plugin.version>2.18.1</maven-surefire-report-plugin.version>
    <!--  Dependencies [COMPILE]:  -->
    <httpclient.version>4.4.1</httpclient.version>
    <httpcore.version>4.4.1</httpcore.version>
    <commons-logging.version>1.2</commons-logging.version>
    <joda-time.version>2.8</joda-time.version>
    <commons-lang3.version>3.4</commons-lang3.version>
    <!--  Dependencies [TEST]:  -->
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <hamcrest-all.version>1.3</hamcrest-all.version>
    <mockito-core.version>1.10.19</mockito-core.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.12</slf4j.version>
    <logback.version>1.1.3</logback.version>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- handle broken builds on jdk1.8 due to doclint function -->
        <id>default-jdk18-profile</id>
        <activation>
            <jdk>[1.8,)</jdk>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <javadoc.doclint.param>-Xdoclint:none</javadoc.doclint.param>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>release-sign-artifacts</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>gpg.passphrase</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-gpg-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>sign</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>MIT License</name>
        <url>http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT</url>
        <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
</licenses>

<issueManagement>
    <url>https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/issues</url>
    <system>GitHub Issues</system>
</issueManagement>

<ciManagement>
    <system>travis</system>
    <url>https://travis-ci.org/OfficeDev/ews-java-api</url>
</ciManagement>

<scm>
    <url>https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api</url>
    <connection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com:OfficeDev/ews-java-api.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com:OfficeDev/ews-java-api.git</developerConnection>
</scm>

<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>ossrh-snapshot</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
        <id>ossrh</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2</url>

    </repository>
</distributionManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>${httpcore.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-logging.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>${joda-time.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>${hamcrest-all.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito-core.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

<!-- Added Dependency -->
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.ews-java-api</groupId>
        <artifactId>ews-java-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Deployment / build plugins -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${nexus-staging-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Ref.: http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/staging-deployment.html -->
                <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                <source>${javaLanguage.version}</source>
                <target>${javaLanguage.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-javadoc-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <linksource>true</linksource>
                <additionalparam>${javadoc.doclint.param}</additionalparam>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-source-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>animal-sniffer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${animal-sniffer-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <signature>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.signature</groupId>
                    <artifactId>java16-sun</artifactId>
                    <version>${animal-sniffer-maven-plugin.signature.version}</version>
                </signature>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>check-java16-sun</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Deployment / build plugins END -->
    </plugins>
    <!-- Used to bump all of the various core plugins up to Maven current.
        Use this in conjunction with the versions-maven-plugin to keep your Maven
        plugins up to date. -->
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-site-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Basic report generation. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-project-info-reports-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Dependency version reporting. Relies on standard version numbering
            - you should use standard version numbering too!
            http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/version-rules.html -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${versions-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>dependency-updates-report</report>
                        <report>plugin-updates-report</report>
                        <report>property-updates-report</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Generates the Javadoc for the report. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-javadoc-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <linksource>true</linksource>
                <additionalparam>${javadoc.doclint.param}</additionalparam>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Generates a nice HTML linked source cross-reference. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-jxr-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-report-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
      <repositories>
<repository>
  <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
  <name>Sonatype OSS Snapshots</name>
  <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
  <releases>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </releases>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </snapshots>
</repository>
```

Comment: You are using an IDE? check the build path, please

Comment: If you install successfuly, means your JAR file is located in your target, or in your local maven repository {userhome}/.m2/repositories ... User the JAR file in your other project's lib, or simply use maven again by adding the artifact as your dependency.

Comment: Please check if your jar file in class path of not?

Comment: could you post your `pom.xml` file `<dependencies>...</dependencies>` content? maybe defining `<scope>compile</scope>` for the exchange library could help

Comment: I've added the pom.xml file, and the mvn path. I'm not using an IDE, I'm doing the project on cmd line on my mac. I'm not exactly sure what the path should be, does that look right?

Answer (score 0):

Two suspected areas we can have as mentioned in the Comments.

1. Either you don't have dependency for Jar contains the mentioned class.
2. Or If its present then problem is with the .classpath file.

@user1933888/  @Ferdinand Neman/  @Subodh Joshi are very right.

@Zavael- By default scope is compile need not to define explicitly. 
REFER: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Note: I Don't have right to add comment above so I mentioned here.
I am newbie to this portal:-)

Answer (score 0):

So the solution to the problem was much simpler than expected..

I was compiling my file with javac, and did not put my class into a package to compile with mvn.

Also, the imports were a tad off because they were not as advertised from some source code. So of course mvn was building correctly, I was just trying to access the classes in an incorrect manner.

Thanks for the help!